# Typescript passing generic class as parameter

Tags: typescript, types, parameters

This code is posing a problem to me:

```
var makeVariableOfClass = (sentClass: typeof Entity) => {
    var newEntity = new sentClass();
}

interface EntityProps {
    sentient: boolean;
}

class Entity {
    private sentient: boolean;
    constructor(props: EntityProps) {
        this.sentient = props.sentient
    }
}

class Person extends Entity {
    constructor() {
        super({sentient: true});
    }
}

class Wall extends Entity {
    constructor() {
        super({sentient: false});
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to programmatically declare either a person or a wall (in this example), but the typing of Entity in makeVariableOfClass requires the EntityProps, even though I only want to send in a subset of things (Person and Wall). I understand that I could make `sentClass` be of type `typeof Person | typeof Wall`, but I'd like to be more scalable than that. Is there another way to get around this without `typeof Person | typeof Wall | typeof ...` ?

Comment: Are you getting an error? This should work if you give entity a default constructor. Currently it seems like you cannot just call `new sentClass()` because it wants you to pass in props.

Comment: new sentClass() would demote Wall and Person to Entity.

Comment: @RossBush was that in response to B. Witter? I have a similar concern with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make `sentClass` be a constructor function with zero parameters that returns something that is compatible with `Entity`:

```
let makeVariableOfClass = <TEntity extends Entity>(
  sentClass: new () => TEntity
) => {
  let newEntity = new sentClass();
  return newEntity;
};

const person = makeVariableOfClass(Person); // person: Person
const wall = makeVariableOfClass(Wall); // wall: Wall
const entity = makeVariableOfClass(Entity); // ERR since Entity does not have a zero-arg constructor
const date = makeVariableOfClass(Date); // ERR since new Date does not produce Entity-compatible value
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by sending in a constructor function, similar to y2bd's answer but not exactly the same:

```
let makeVariableOfClass = (createNewClass: () => Entity) => {
  return createNewClass();
}
```

Obviously this is a bit obtuse in this particular example, but it served my purposes of telling the abstract map class what types of walls to use for different map subclasses.

Comment: So you don't care if `makeVariableOfClass(Person)` returns an `Entity` instead of specifically a `Person`?

Comment: @jcalz Does the above answer prevent that? Is <TEntity extends Entity> preventing that from happening?

Comment: Yes, the other version is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function which means that `TEntity` will be inferred to be the specific instance type of the `sentClass` parameter passed in.  If you call `makeVariableOfClass(Person)`, then `sentClass` is of type `new () => Person` which will cause the compiler to infer that `TEntity` is `Person`, and thus the return type of the function will also be `Person`.